# Node JS : Error with res.download() after res.render()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm beginning with Node JS, and I get an error :

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

You can see my code, the problem is with `res.download()`;
Or, how can I show the view without `res.render()`?

Can you tell me how to fix this issue? Thanks you!

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var pythonShell = require('python-shell');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('style'));

app.post('/downloads', function(req, res) {                                 
  res.render('downloads.ejs');
  console.log("Python script begins");
  pythonShell.run('./generator.py', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Python Script Ended");
    res.download('mapCreated.tiff', 'map.tiff');
  });
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

Comment: You are sending response twice - `res.render` and `res.download`.

Comment: I know that it is the problem, but I don't know how to show the view, and make the download :/

Comment: make a different route to handle the download alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending `res.download` after `res.render`. this will try to send the response again, but you can't send response two times. That is what is causing the error `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

What you need to do is `render` the view first( you can send a `get` request to render the view) and when that view is loaded, call `another route` to `download` the file( send `post` route to download)

```
app.get('/downloads', function(req, res) { 
    res.render('downloads.ejs');
});

app.post('/downloads', function (req,res){
    console.log("Python script begins");
    pythonShell.run('./generator.py', function (err) { 
        if (err) throw err; 
        console.log("Python Script Ended");
        res.download('mapCreated.tiff', 'map.tiff');
    }); 
})
```